# Service in Angular is instantiated twice when extending the service with another service

Tags: angular, inheritance, service, singleton, extend

In my Angular project, I have a setup with multiple services. One service has some functions for which I want to restrict access, so that it can only be used from one specific other service.

To achieve this, I want to extend the service in the calling service, and use the protected access modifier to restrict access. However, upon implementing this, I see that the parent service has two instances when I start the application. How can I enforce that the parent service is instantiated only once, as singleton? Or, how should I approach this problem differently to ensure access to the functions in one service are only accesible from the calling service?

The parent service pseudo code:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ParentService {

  constructor() {
    // below is logged twice!
    console.log('new instance of ParentService created');
  }

  public someFunction() {}

  protected functionIWantToLimitAccessTo() {}

}
```

The child service pseudo code:

```
import { ParentService} from './parent.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChildService extends ParentService {

  constructor() {
    super();  // <- this super() call is needed for class extension
  }

  public publicFunction() {
    super.functionIWantToLimitAccessTo();
  }

}
```

I would have expected there to be only one instance of ParentService in this setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

By providing the ParentService in app.module.ts instead of in the component itself, I can specify the class I want to inject for the ParentService. I my case, that's the ChildService.

This way I can inject the ParentService and ChildService everywhere in the application, but I have restricted the access op protected functions of the ParentService to the ChildService only.

**parent service:**

```
// No longer registered as injectable component here
// @Injectable({
//   providedIn: 'root'
// })
export abstract class ParentService {

  constructor() {
    // below is logged only once now!
    console.log('new instance of ParentService created');
  }

  public someFunction() {}

  protected functionIWantToLimitAccessTo() {}
}
```

**child service:**

```
import { ParentService} from './parent.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChildService extends ParentService {

  constructor() {
    super();  // <- this super() call is needed for class extension

    // I can call protected function from ParentService from here
    super.functionIWantToLimitAccessTo();
  }

    
}
```

**Usage in component:**

```
import { ParentService} from './parent.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RandomComponent {

  constructor(private parentService: ParentService) {

    // I can call public functions from ParentService
    this.parentService.someFunction();

    // I can NOT call protected function from ParentService here
    this.parentService.functionIWantToLimitAccessTo(); // -> compiler error
  }
}
```

**And in `app.module.ts` I have:**

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: ParentService, useClass: ChildService}
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use the power of dependencies injection? and inject the needed service to your constructor

```
 import { ParentService} from './parent.service';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ChildService  {
    
    
      constructor(private parentService: ParentService) {
      }
    
    
      public publicFunction() {
        this.parentService.unctionIWantToLimitAccessTo();
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @bik, I could do this. However, I want to restrict access to the functions in the parent service. This way, I would have to give the function `public` as access modifier in the parent service. That's why I figured I should extend the parent service with the child service, to make use of the `protected` access modifier.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you experience is exactly how it's supposed to work. All the services that have the `@Injectable` annotation are managed by Angular's [Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) engine. You can use a service by injecting it in the constructor of your component or service like this:

```
constructor(private serviceToInject: ServiceToInject) {}
```

Since both of your services are using this annotation, I guess that also your parent service is used like this somewhere in your application. Otherwise, it would not need the annotation.

The logging will occur twice, since you now have two *different* services, that both call the log-method on initialization:

- ParentService (executes it's constructor directly)
- ChildService *of type* ParentService (executes parents constructor)

When you use inheritance, you do not just reference an instance of your ParentService, you create a new service that *inherits* all the behaviour of the ParentService.

To solve your problem there are different approaches:

##### 1st Approach

You can simply just get rid of the restricted methods of ParentService completely and copy them into the ChildService direclty, since you said, "it can only be used from one specific other service."

##### 2nd Approach

Make use of Angular's DI engine and just follow the injection as described above.

##### Add-On to this:

By default, all the services are generated by the Angular CLI with the option `{providedIn: 'root'}`. When you want to restrict access, you can get rid of that parameter here and provide it to the components, that should be able to use this service manually. (See [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#providing-services) for more details)

Comment: Thanks @Sir Leo. I totally agree with you. The thing is, the functions I want to restrict access to in the parent service use private properties of the parent service, which I don't want to move all over to the child service. So I guess my only option is making the functions public, proceed with regular DI, and keep an eye out for not accidentally calling those public functions in the parent service from any component in the application that shouldn't have access. It'll probably be fine, but I would have liked not risking unnecessary exposure when working with more developers on this project.